# Errors while initializing one node Hadoop using Cloudera Manager

Tags: linux, hadoop, cloudera

I am using Cloudera Virtualbox. I am trying to set one node hadoop cluster using cloudera manager. this is the error I am getting.

```
BEGIN yum makecache
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
http://beta.cloudera.com/search/redhat/6/x86_64/search/0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] 
PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: cdh-solr.
Please verify its path and try again
END (1)
Installing jdk package...
BEGIN yum list installed jdk
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Installed Packages
jdk.x86_64 2000:1.6.0_31-fcs @cloudera-manager
END (0)
BEGIN echo jdk cloudera-manager-agent cloudera-manager-daemons | grep jdk
jdk cloudera-manager-agent cloudera-manager-daemons
END (0)
BEGIN yum info jdk
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
* base: mirror.as24220.net
* epel: mirror.as24220.net
* extras: mirror.colocity.com
* updates: centos.mirror.crucial.com.au
http://beta.cloudera.com/search/redhat/6/x86_64/search/0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14]
PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: cdh-solr
Please verify its path and try again
END (1)
remote package jdk is not available, giving up
waiting for rollback request
```

Any Idea what might be the reason?

Thanks,
Ashwin

Comment: One can't access "http://beta.cloudera.com/search/redhat/6/x86_64/search/0/repodata/repomd.xml" ! Check your yum repo and put the correct URL

Comment: I kind of realized that..sometime back..Now I am looking for the file where I have to edit it. I think its in /etc/yum.repos.d/cdh-solr..am I right?

Comment: Yes, it should be somewhere there. `grep cloudera /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. I thought I will answer my own question. It might help others. 
The issue was the latest clouder manager is 4.7.1. But the cloudera VM available on their website has cloudera manager 4.6.
So upgrading the manager through the VM will help in getting past the jdk installation errror.
Here is a link which has all the information regarding updrading the manager.
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Administration-Guide/cmag_upgrade_cm4_to_4.html

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the file that contained that repo, and I was able to successfully update using yum.

```
$ sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/cloudera-search.repo
$ sudo yum update
```

If you need to use Cloudera Search, this is not the solution you want.